# Given A, B matrices, prove BA is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A_{5x7}$, $B_{7x5}$, prove that $BA$ is singular.

This is what I did:

Matrix $A$ is $5x7$. That means, there are 7 parameters with 5 equations. There are at least 2 free variables, so the solution for $A\underline{x}=\underline{0}$ is non-trivial. 
BA means each $i$ column of B multiplies each $i$ column of A, where $1≤i≤7$. The column with the free variables also multiplied by the corresponding B column. This leads to free variables multiplied by a scalar, so the outcome solution is still non-trivial.

I'm afraid that is not how the proof goes...

Comment: There is some $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax=0$. Then $BA x= 0$ and hence it is singular.

Comment: I'd say your solution isn't well written but the idea is sound: as $5<7$ there is a nonzero vector $x$ with $Ax=0$. Then $BAx=0$, but if $BA$ were nonsingular then $x=0$, a contradiction. We conclude that $BA$ is singular.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$A$ is $5 \times 7$ implies $Ax=0$ has  a non zero solution.